# How can I add a line in my Javascript to allow navigating my site with a track pad and up/down arrows?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vertical-scrolling

I'm trying to add a javascript event to enable vertical navigation using the track pad and up/down arrow keys on a laptop. On the desktop I have the "mouse wheel" as a way to navigate the site.

I've tried multiple plugins to attempt to get it to work but to no avail.

Comment: Normally if you use two fingers on your track pad, it simulated a mouse wheel event no?

Comment: Not on my end - This is the link. http://biomodex.wpengine.com/?page_id=6485&et_fb=1

Comment: Could you please add the plugins you tried to use so that people won't re-suggest them?

Comment: Yes, also can I add the actual Javascipt here that I have in my integration tab?  The plugins I tried #1 WP Smoother - Smooth Scroll, Anchor Scroll, Fade Animations, #2 MouseWheel Smooth Scroll, #3 Yet Another Smooth Scroll